# ¿Por qué al cerrar un ObjectInputStream con close() se lanza una IOException?

Tags: java, lista, excepciones, archivo

Estoy intentando recuperar los datos de una lista ligada desde un archivo serializable, en este archivo lo que guardo son los nodos de la lista, para esto en mi clase ListaLigadaOrdenada incluyo la siguiente función

```
public void recuperarLista(String nombreFichero) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
     ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nombreFichero));
     Nodo aux;
     aux = (Nodo) entrada.readObject();
     aux.setSig(null);
     this.raiz = aux;
     while (aux != null) {
         aux = (Nodo) entrada.readObject();
         if(aux!=null){
             aux.setSig(null);
             this.insertarNodo(aux);
         }
     }
     entrada.close();
 }
```

Aseguro que siempre haya al menos un objeto en el archivo así que de eso no hay problema, de hecho, recupera todos los nodos guardados en el archivo leído pero siempre lanza una IOException y no logro entender porqué, estas excepciones las capturo en el main y si pongo en el catch de la IOException lo mismo que debería de hacer en el caso de que no ocurriera el programa va de la misma manera.

He puesto algunos println que he quitado en el código de esta publicación y todo va muy bien hasta que llega al close(), puse uno antes de este y otro después y solo el que estaba antes ha salido en consola, lo que me hace pensar que es esta la sentencia que lanza la excepción.

Les agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme a entender qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal :)

Me pidieron que colocara los detalles de la excepción así que añadí una printStackTrace() en la parte donde recibo la IOException y esto es lo que muestra

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3038)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1597)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
at ListaLigada.ListaLigadaOrdenada.recuperarLista(Parcial3_AcostaCarrascoCarlos_Programa.java:386)
at ListaLigada.Lamina$PulsaBoton.actionPerformed(Parcial3_AcostaCarrascoCarlos_Programa.java:193)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Por lo que veo es una excepción de fin de archivo pero mi condición de lectura por lo que tengo entendido debería de detenerse antes de llegar al fin del archivo.

Comment: Porqué no metes el código de esa función entre un try-catch e imprimes el mensaje de la excepción? Así podrías volver y decirnos qué excepción te da.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, realmente hacía falta :) ya añadí lo que muestra la excepción, aunque sigo sin entender entonces cómo debería de ser la condición de paro

Comment: El stacktrace explica que la excepción se lanza al llamar a `readObject`, no a `close`

Answer (score 1):

Pues ahí lo tienes:

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached
> unexpectedly during input. This exception is mainly used by data input
> streams to signal end of stream

Que traducido sería más o menos:

> Indica que se ha alcanzado el final de un archivo o de una secuencia
> inesperadamente durante la entrada. Esta excepción la utilizan
> principalmente los flujos de entrada de datos para indicar el final
> del flujo.

Dado que lees datos hasta que el dato sea `null`, hay una lectura que haces que llega al final del fichero y entonces, se produce la excepción.

La solución sencilla sería capturar ahí esa excepción con un `try-catch`, y no hacer nada en el `catch`. Asumir que vale, has llegado al final y no hay más que hacer. Algo como esto:

```
try {
   //Tu código
} catch( EOFException ex) {
   //No tienes nada que hacer aquí más que asumir que se ha terminado
   //el fichero.
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, de hecho fue lo que hice en mi programa y corre como si nada pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de evitar que lance la excepción